# Laravel record being deleted when calling Factory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo, factory

I have two tables - **Roles** and **Users**. Inside of Roles, I have a single record.

```
{
  id: 1, name: Employee, timestamps: blahblah
}
```

The strange thing is, whenever I call my User factory (which has a foreign key for field role_id) it deletes the record in the Roles table. It also fails the creation of the factory instantiation, saying that the **role_id foreign key constraint fails**. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is the code for the user factory. I've hardcoded values until I can figure it out.

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
 return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => Hash::make("12341234"),
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    'company_id' => 1,
    'role_id' => 1,
 ];
});
```

And the error:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`app`.`users`, CONSTRAINT
>   `users_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles`
>   (`id`))

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This error shows that the role table not find. This factory code execute before executing the role table.

Just change the order for execution for database table if you can using the foriegn key.

Comment: What is the command you execute?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by order for execution. I know it can find the roles table as I can create and fine Role records in Tinker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to figure out the exact weirdness associated with this, I believe it to be related to the database configuration for PHPUnit. I added the following lines to my phpunit.xml which resolved the issue.

It's also worth mentioning that the **role** entity was being deleted  because the test was using **RefreshDatabase**.

```
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite" />
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:" />
```

Comment: as @usrNotFound pointed out you normally use different database for testing.

Comment: Yes - I assume that the default database configuration for phpunit isn't the same as Laravel's, which is probably what caused the issue. That being said it's still confusing as to why the foreign constraints failed specifically.

Comment: It had nothing to do with the hardcoded vs factory generated role_id though.

Answer (score 2):

Your foreign key validation seems to be the issue as you error says.

The given context your role_id seems to be the foreign key and you are just passing an arbitrary value which you will never work.

To resolve you will have to create a factory Method that creates a new role and do the following

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
 return [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'password' => Hash::make("12341234"),
    'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    'company_id' => 1,
    'role_id' => factory(Role::class)->create()->id,
 ];
});
```

PS make sure your mass assignment includes role_id

Comment: But in this hypothetical situation if... factory(Role::class)->create()->id == 1, why wouldn't replacing it with 1 (which is the ID of the record currently in the table) work?

Comment: Have you heard about `YAGNI`? Secondly, you should be able to pass role_id like `factory(Role::class)->create(['role_id' =>1)->id`. What are you using your model factory for anyway? have a look at https://laravel-news.com/learn-to-use-model-factories-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: I'm using the factory in a feature test - never heard of YAGNI but this is just standard TDD. I'm using model factories to perform various functionality as a user. Again the main weirdness here is that calling the factory DELETES the record in the roles table with the matching id, then throws the error.

Comment: when you run test laravel uses `RefreshDatabase` trait which will refresh the database every time you run the test. Make sure you have a different database for test or in memory storage.  Have a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503921/laravel-unit-test-variable-of-integer-data-type-is-coming-as-string-while-un/49504398#49504398 on how to set up you test

Comment: While putting the testing in memory resolved the issue, it's still strange that it would fail from a foreign key constraint, which means it was able to find the correct table in the correct database. I'm glad it's fixed but I still don't understand why the insertion failed.

Comment: Seems to me like you are new to the whole thing. Normally you run a test on empty database, memory whatever .... In your case, the database wasn't empty and laravel uses RefreshDatabase trait for testing which makes your database clean i.e empty.  Please do read more about testing.

Comment: Correct, hence my question =)

Comment: hope my comment made some sense. I recommend laracast. Good place to learn everything laravel and testing with laravel. Good luck